# How can I get eclipse to wipe the user data for my app before running it again

Tags: android, eclipse

I am not using the emulator (to slow), and am debugging on actual device (Incredible). I have noticed that even if I go to the phones `menu >> settings  >> applications >> my app` and force stop and clear data, if I run from `eclipse` again right after, some old values persist.  I have not noticed this problem if I uninstall the app and then run it from eclipse.

Is there a way to have `eclipse` uninstall the app every time, or is there an option like the one one the emulator to target/wipe user data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On the command line it should be as simple as

```
adb uninstall <package name>
```

Where adb is the full path to adb if you have not placed it in your path or made an alias for it. (It's easiest to place it in your path).

Updated thanks to @alextsc

Comment: Definitely the way to go. I have the cmd console open at all times when testing on a device or the emulator.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I think I have figured out my problem, and it is nothing to do with the old app data.  I was leaving an alarm with data in the extras active and when I installed the revised app, it picked up the old intent when the alarm triggered.  I am a rookie with java and sometimes it shows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this may not be the best way but it's something I do. I have a method in my first activity that wipes all the user data and I set a simple flag to either run the method (during development) or not run the method (during production). This saves me a **lot** of time in not having to install/uninstall the app on a phone.